# Evil as the opposite category of 

Tags: category-theory, evil

*Presupposition of the question*: the drastic-difference thesis, which is here based on [the SEP article on the concept of evil](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/concept-evil/):

> Since World War II, moral, political, and legal philosophers have become increasingly interested in the concept of evil. This interest has been partly motivated by ascriptions of ‘evil’ by laymen, social scientists, journalists, and politicians as they try to understand and respond to various atrocities and horrors, such as genocides, terrorist attacks, mass murders, and tortures and killing sprees by psychopathic serial killers. It seems that we cannot capture the moral significance of these actions and their perpetrators by calling them ‘wrong’ or ‘bad’ or even ‘very very wrong’ or ‘very very bad.’ We need the concept of evil.

Now, suppose a category with initial, terminal, and zero objects, a category called **Value**. Following Kant, if we reverse the appropriate priority of duties/virtues relative to happiness/hypothetical imperatives, we have given ourselves to radical evil. Would this mean that **Evil** = **Value**<sup>op</sup>, here? Or, to fully capture the essence of the drastic-difference thesis, would we have to go to something more like **Metavalue** first, with disvalue as an object of some "kind," internally opposite to another object = value, and then take **Metavalue**<sup>op</sup> = **Evil**? Would that be drastic enough, or perhaps *too* drastic? (As far as interpreting Kant goes, I suppose I should differentiate **Diablos Malum** from **Radix Malum** instead of just having generic **Malum**, here; or then there are diabolical objects and radical objects, as initial, terminal, zero, or otherwise objects, of **Evil**, but then this makes it seem like **Evil** is not the opposite of **Value** or even **Metavalue**, since reversing the mappings internal to categories of **Diablos**-objects and **Radix**-objects together would not give us "good" mappings instead?)

**Citation issue:** although I have found tantalizing remarks scattered across the Internet about the ethical applicability of category theory, I have yet to find a fuller, broader treatment than [this one pertaining to deontic logic in the Canadian legal system](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1570868314000573). However, as far as I can tell, the word "evil" does not appear anywhere in that article.

Comment: Are you trying to postulate a "logical" foundation of evil?

Comment: @IoannisPaizis did I use the word "foundation" anywhere in this OP? I seem to be trying to describe something/interpret other theories (drastic-difference/Kant) on whatever terms. Per Kant, the *origins* of evil are supposedly inexplicable, though.

Comment: Deontic calculus modeling 'ought' from 'is' normative reasoning is extremely complicated thus category-theoretic fibration pullback as limit of a diagram is an ideal combining foundation underlying deontic system to give soundness and completeness via trivial monoidal/closed Cartesian structures bi-embeddings as a structure preserving functor between instances of free category for all its fragments such as CNR which is *-autonomous. Ergo at least some fragment has adjunction-like properties such as existence of unit and counit morphisms which may not simply translate to antonyms of ethics...

Comment: The problem is that reversing arrows does not produce anything "drastically" different, it is just the same ‘very very wrong’ upside down (like all opposite categories). The point of a separate evil concept is that evil is something distinct from moral wrongness, no matter how significant, and cannot be flashed out in terms of the Value category alone, or some functor thereof. Perhaps, you should pick some subcategory of Value that keeps some sort of "twistedness", while dropping many usual characteristics that determine its arrows as inessential. But which way they go is a formality.

Comment: This might be better as an answer, but IDK. Anyway: I agree with Conifold's assessment of your approach. I think a more useful approach to a drastic difference between *bad* and *evil* is the idea of *positive moral obligation to oppose* (evil) vs *prohibition against* (bad). That is bad which one is prohibited to do; that is evil which one is both prohibited to do and obligated to oppose.

Comment: @gs yeah, I might take evil and good for opposites, but I don't know that they're opposites in the same way as two categories can be opposed as such. But I'm having an even harder time processing my category-theory studies than my set-theory ones, so maybe my analysis is doomed regardless (for now!).

Comment: @KristianBerry another useful approach might be to assume for the sake of investigation that evil is inseparable from its religious connotations in whatever language you're looking at. Self-reporting on the presence or magnitude of a "drastic difference" between people whose primary cultural experience is that of a culture not derived from 1st century Judaism vs those whose culture is so derived might provide a test for this hypothesis.

Comment: what is it you call "value" here? Or are you saying there is something that is the opposite of evil and trying to define it?

Comment: @armand for better or worse, I finished my attempts to understand ethics using set theory, so I wondered if I could add to my understanding by turning to category theory also. Unfortunately, the barrage of symbolism and diagrams is even more overwhelming here than it has been with set theory, so I feel like my understanding is going almost nowhere right now :/

Answer (score -1):

This idea has merit. Value has also been used to connote meaning. So disvalue would be equivalent to meaninglessness. Panpsychism suggests that the universe creates value as it develops. Your idea suggests that evil destroys value and meaning.

Comment: I appreciate the upvote, but I should note that by "opposite category" I mean a technical matter of category theory, where mappings are reversed across the board but opposite *objects* are not so in view. What I need are opposite objects, though... Maybe Alessio Moretti's "logical geometry of opposition" would be helpful?

Comment: I appreciate your candour. I will return the favour. I had enough of technical matters when I was a scientist. But thanks, you got me thinking.

Answer (score -1):

Pure evil is actions that are done with the aim of devaluing **or** disformatting the self. All Counterfeitics and some Realistics reach pure evil. Pure transcendent evil, on the other hand, is **synthetic propaganda** aimed at eliminating meaning and context. Some Realistics can practice pure transcendent evil.

Comment: So which category, or *n*-category it would turn out, I suppose, do you think that **Evil** can be reflected out of? **Value** or even **Metavalue** seem too low in the hierarchy of categories, except for **Radix Malum** (per Kant's sense of that phrase, that is).

Comment: Nothing and space is Counterfeitics. I inverted nothing and there is a universe for ready to exploding. I do it again; Any of the things that aren't. It's not even evil.